# Магарыч пишется в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

Магарыч (взятка) пишется в кавычках?

Comment: @shampar овеществлённая благодарность во многих случаях и является взяткой.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки не нужны, это слово фиксируется словарями.

Answer (score 1):

**Кавычки не нужны:**

МАГАРЫЧ,  [от араб. mahārij - расходы, издержки]. Разг.-сниж. Угощение, выпивка в связи с заключением выгодной сделки, получения премии, С меня м. причитается. Ставить, поставить м.

Пример: Сделав свое дело, Славуня... промычал с некоторой застенчивостью: ― **Магарыч** с тебя, соседушка… Англичанка не поняла. [Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт» (1999)].

Answer (score 1):

**магарыч**
 *Прост.* Угощение по поводу заключения выгодной сделки, заключения какого-либо договора и т.п., которое ставит сторона, получившая в этой сделке барыш.
[Большов:] *Как сделаешь все.., такой тебе, Сысой Псоич, **магарыч** поставлю, просто сказать, угоришь.*
А. Островский, Свои люди — сочтемся.

//Взятка, подарок за содействие в каком-либо деле, в какой-либо сделке.
*— Оклады [у чиновников] все-таки нищенские. А соблазн — огромный и там, в губернии... Каждый норовит предложить тебе **магарыч.***
Боборыкин, Из новых.

Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том II, 1958.

В любом случае(при любом значении) слово ***магарыч*** кавычками не выделяется (кроме, например, марки самогонного аппарата или названия магазина).